# GeoServe crashing after adding GeoFence jar libraries

Tags: java, tomcat, gis, geoserver

I'm using GeoServer 2.6.2.

I add GeoFence jar files to ~/geoserver/WEB-INF/lib.

The jar files: `gs-geofence-2.6-SNAPSHOT.jar`, `geofence-services-api-2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar` and `geofence-model-2.2-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

Now when I want to create new **LayerGroup** dose not work.

[GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/release/2.6.2/)

[GeoFence Plugin](http://ares.opengeo.org/geoserver/2.6.x/community-latest/geoserver-2.6-SNAPSHOT-geofence-plugin.zip)

Details:

[image]

> org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using
>   constructor public org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage() at
>   org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:212)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:57)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:298)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:320)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
>   at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329) at
>   org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1436) at
>   org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545) at
>   org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:484)
>   at
>   org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:138)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723) at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:159)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617) at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:116)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
>   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:135)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
>   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:76)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42) at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>   at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>   at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526) at
>   org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:192)
>   ... 98 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.put(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1124)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.catalog.impl.ModificationProxyCloner.getDeepestCatalogInfoInterface(ModificationProxyCloner.java:173)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.catalog.impl.ModificationProxyCloner.clone(ModificationProxyCloner.java:77)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.catalog.impl.ModificationProxyCloner.cloneCollection(ModificationProxyCloner.java:200)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.catalog.impl.ModificationProxy.invoke(ModificationProxy.java:110)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy31.getLayers(Unknown Source) at
>   org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.checkAccess(SecureCatalogImpl.java:630)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.filterGroups(SecureCatalogImpl.java:963)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.security.SecureCatalogImpl.getLayerGroups(SecureCatalogImpl.java:312)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.catalog.impl.AbstractFilteredCatalog.getLayerGroups(AbstractFilteredCatalog.java:250)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.catalog.impl.AbstractCatalogDecorator.getLayerGroups(AbstractCatalogDecorator.java:458)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.catalog.impl.LocalWorkspaceCatalog.getLayerGroups(LocalWorkspaceCatalog.java:199)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.web.demo.PreviewLayerProvider.getItems(PreviewLayerProvider.java:70)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerDataProvider.fullSize(GeoServerDataProvider.java:237)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel$PagerDelegate.updateMatched(GeoServerTablePanel.java:566)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel$PagerDelegate.(GeoServerTablePanel.java:559)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel.(GeoServerTablePanel.java:171)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.web.wicket.GeoServerTablePanel.(GeoServerTablePanel.java:96)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage$1.(MapPreviewPage.java:64)
>   at
>   org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage.(MapPreviewPage.java:64)
>   ... 103 more

Comment: I think you will need to find geofence-plugin-2.6.2.jar rather than the snapshot jar you are using.

Comment: @ iant Here is plugins repository, there is only snapshot artifacts: http://ares.opengeo.org/geoserver/2.6.x/community-latest/

Comment: Then you need snapshot GeoServer

Comment: I'm sure this is a bug. This problem also occurs in the latest version of GeoServer (2.7.1.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is a bug and can be fix with one line change in GeofenceAccessManager.java

The github commit link:
https://github.com/esmailzadeh/geoserver/commit/863528e26f301a6f1f6b41e6c0912af008e7ff27

Comment: Yes im working with goserver 2.6.2 and geofence 2.2, this bug is still exist in geoserver 2.8 and the commit should merge to master branch to fix the bug.